# How to wrap objects printed by jQuery html() function individually

Tags: jquery

You can see my code here:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var anchor_navigation_content = $('#content h1').text();
    $('#anchor-navigation').html(anchor_navigation_content);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="anchor-navigation"></div>
<div id="content">
    <h1>Test1</h1>
    <h1>Test2</h1>
</div>
```

I'm trying to create a navigation that is automatically generated based on each H1 tag that appears within my #content. Each element should be wrapped, individually, with an a tag. However, my code is wrapping all of the elements in *one* a tag. I'm not sure how to overcome this. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[wrapInner](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner) will take care of it, you shouldn't wrap an `h1` with an `a` anyway. Wrap it's contents.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#anchor-navigation').html($('#content h1').clone().wrapInner("<a href='#'></a>"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="anchor-navigation"></div>
<div id="content">
    <h1>Test1</h1>
    <h1>Test2</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `.each()`

```js
$('#content h1').each(function () {
    $('#anchor-navigation').append("<a href='#'>" + $(this).text() + "</a>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="anchor-navigation"></div>
<div id="content">
     <h1>Test1</h1>
     <h1>Test2</h1>
</div>
```

`.each()` will loop through every h1 inside #content, wrap text of each h1 with `a` and append it to #anchor-navigation with `.append()`

- http://api.jquery.com/each/